# How do people protect against 307 redirect

Tags: http, security, redirect, web, browser

If evilsite.com submits a form to evilsite.com/foo and then 307 redirects to goodsite.com/bar where a user is already logged in, this will send the POST with goodsites cookie to goodsite.com/bar.

How do people usually protect against this?
Do normal webframeworks django/flask do anything to protect against this?

I can see two ways of protecting against this:

1. put a token into your pages that is sent with every form (not cookie).
   This seems like a lot of work.
2. look at the referrer header. But there are browser plugins that suppress the referrer or worse just pretend the destination is the referrer. And I'm not sure how reliable this referrer header is.

Comment: I see that stackoverflow indeed always includes a hidden input field called 'fkey' in every form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called [CSRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery). You should use anti CSRF tokens to prevent this kind of vulnerability. All modern frameworks can deal with it.